# F# compiler: A type instantiation involves a byref type

Tags: f#, byref

I have a problem and a solution. I don't understand why the solution works.

Here is some code that breaks the F# compiler with the message "A type instantiation involves a byref type":

```
let updateExternalLoginProperty(isEnabled: bool byref, value: bool, name: string) =
    let anyExternalLoginEnabledBeforePropertyIsSet = this.AnyExternalLoginEnabled
    this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(&isEnabled, value, name) |> ignore
    if (this.AnyExternalLoginEnabled <> anyExternalLoginEnabledBeforePropertyIsSet) then this.RaisePropertyChanged("AnyExternalLoginEnabled")

member this.FacebookLoginEnabled with get() = facebookLoginEnabled  and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty(&facebookLoginEnabled, value, "FacebookLoginEnabled")
member this.GoogleLoginEnabled with get() = googleLoginEnabled and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty(&googleLoginEnabled, value, "GoogleLoginEnabled") |> ignore
member this.MicrosoftLoginEnabled with get() = microsoftLoginEnabled and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty(&microsoftLoginEnabled, value, "MicrosoftLoginEnabled") |> ignore
member this.TwitterLoginEnabled with get() = twitterLoginEnabled and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty(&twitterLoginEnabled, value, "TwitterLoginEnabled") |> ignore
member this.AzureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled with get() = azureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty(&azureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled, value, "AzureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled") |> ignore
member this.AnyExternalLoginEnabled with get() = this.FacebookLoginEnabled || this.GoogleLoginEnabled || this.MicrosoftLoginEnabled || this.TwitterLoginEnabled || this.AzureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled
```

The compiler error is highlighted under the call to `updateExternalLoginProperty`.

To make the compiler error go away, I can simply change the `let` binding to a private member variable:

```
member private this.UpdateExternalLoginProperty(isEnabled: bool byref, value: bool, name: string) =
    let anyExternalLoginEnabledBeforePropertyIsSet = this.AnyExternalLoginEnabled
    this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(&isEnabled, value, name) |> ignore
    if (this.AnyExternalLoginEnabled <> anyExternalLoginEnabledBeforePropertyIsSet) then this.RaisePropertyChanged("AnyExternalLoginEnabled")

member this.FacebookLoginEnabled with get() = facebookLoginEnabled  and set(value) = this.UpdateExternalLoginProperty(&facebookLoginEnabled, value, "FacebookLoginEnabled")
member this.GoogleLoginEnabled with get() = googleLoginEnabled and set(value) = this.UpdateExternalLoginProperty(&googleLoginEnabled, value, "GoogleLoginEnabled") |> ignore
member this.MicrosoftLoginEnabled with get() = microsoftLoginEnabled and set(value) = this.UpdateExternalLoginProperty(&microsoftLoginEnabled, value, "MicrosoftLoginEnabled") |> ignore
member this.TwitterLoginEnabled with get() = twitterLoginEnabled and set(value) = this.UpdateExternalLoginProperty(&twitterLoginEnabled, value, "TwitterLoginEnabled") |> ignore
member this.AzureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled with get() = azureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled and set(value) = this.UpdateExternalLoginProperty(&azureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled, value, "AzureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled") |> ignore
member this.AnyExternalLoginEnabled with get() = this.FacebookLoginEnabled || this.GoogleLoginEnabled || this.MicrosoftLoginEnabled || this.TwitterLoginEnabled || this.AzureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled
```

And this does everything it is supposed to do (i.e. the UI shows a separator only when there are external logins available). What I don't understand is why this change should fix the compilation.

Is the type instantiation the compiler referring to the creation of the `updateExternalLoginProperty` function? Why would turning it into a member variable circumvent this illegal type instantiation?

And as a side-question, when is `nameof` coming in F#? These magic strings make me sad.

**UPDATE**

Based on ildjam's answer (you can't have a byref in a tuple), I went back to the `let` binding, only with three arguments rather than one:

```
let updateExternalLoginProperty (isEnabled: bool byref) (value: bool) (name: string) =
    let anyExternalLoginEnabledBeforePropertyIsSet = this.AnyExternalLoginEnabled
    this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(&isEnabled, value, name) |> ignore
    if (this.AnyExternalLoginEnabled <> anyExternalLoginEnabledBeforePropertyIsSet) then this.RaisePropertyChanged("AnyExternalLoginEnabled")

member this.FacebookLoginEnabled with get() = facebookLoginEnabled  and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty &facebookLoginEnabled value "FacebookLoginEnabled"
member this.GoogleLoginEnabled with get() = googleLoginEnabled and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty &googleLoginEnabled value "GoogleLoginEnabled"
member this.MicrosoftLoginEnabled with get() = microsoftLoginEnabled and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty &microsoftLoginEnabled value "MicrosoftLoginEnabled"
member this.TwitterLoginEnabled with get() = twitterLoginEnabled and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty &twitterLoginEnabled value "TwitterLoginEnabled"
member this.AzureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled with get() = azureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled and set(value) = updateExternalLoginProperty &azureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled value "AzureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled"
member this.AnyExternalLoginEnabled with get() = this.FacebookLoginEnabled || this.GoogleLoginEnabled || this.MicrosoftLoginEnabled || this.TwitterLoginEnabled || this.AzureActiveDirectoryLoginEnabled
```

This also works. It's an interesting distinction: the member variable has three arguments; the original `let` binding had only one `tuple` argument.

Comment: `member private this.UpdateExternalLoginProperty` takes three arguments, but `let updateExternalLoginProperty` takes a single argument – a tuple of type `bool byref * bool * string`, and `_ byref` is not legal for a tuple element.

Comment: That works. I'll update my question. Thanks,